# Smart text replacement with variable text

Tags: editing

I have an HTML file as following:

```
 <a name="1"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
   a - This is a wonderful day
</h2>
 <a name="1"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
 b - This is a great day
</h2>
 <a name="1"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
 c - This is the best day
</h2>
```

I want to replace the text  with increasing value as following:

```
<a name="1"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
   a - This is a wonderful day
</h2>
 <a name="2"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
 b - This is a great day
</h2>
 <a name="3"></a><h2 dir="RTL">
 c - This is the best day
</h2>
```

Do you know any tool that can do it?

I know that very simple script can do it but I'm sure there are existing tools that can do it.

Comment: Here at [so], we're more into the writing-scripts than the finding-tools ([the latter is in fact off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). If you need help with the former, feel free to post your attempt and ask a specific question about that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.

Comment: What does it need to do exactly?

Comment: I just want to find a fast way to edit a lot of files. I don't want to do it manually